# Read values From xml file and store each row into different list in python

Tags: python, xml, list, load

I have been trying to load values from a xml file and store it in different lists. Can somebody show me a possible way?  Any help is appreciated. 
xml file has 4 rows of float numbers like this:

1.34566 1.56777 1.454534 1.436234 1.363546 1.43642353

2.45432 2.34251 2.324323 2.324232 2.342342 2.23423423

0.45234 0.32423 0.324233 0.324233 0.324234 0.23423432

1.32423 1.43324 1.324334 1.343422 1.324343 1.34234234

I want to import this float numbers into four lists List1,List2,List3,List4 in python.

I know to store it into one list, but i want to store each row into separate list. Can somebody please help me with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of lists and then do whatever you want with the data gathered there.
sample code could be :

```
superList = []    
for x in range(1, your last row):
   temp = []
   while i < your number of columns:
      temp.append(sheet.cell(row = x, column = i).value)
   superList.append(temp)
```

Pretty basic. Where sheet is the variable that "holds" your file.
So what this does, is that it creates a list out of every row and then puts all of these lists in a "super" list. So superList[0] will have the first row, superList[1] the second row etc.

Comment: Thank you. So if I want to use the first three values in first row what should I do ? 
If I do superList[0:3] it gives me first three rows. I was trying to put them in multiple lists so I can easily extract the first three elements of each row ( which would be in separate list)

Comment: If you want the first three values of the first row then you have to access the first row of the superList and then the first 3 elements. That is, superList[0][0], superList[0][1], superList[0][2].